# Merging subgroups from groupby() to form new tables pandas python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('file.csv')
df=df.groupby('category')

print(len(df))
>>>OUT 50
```

I have already grouped my data according to their individual categories using groupby() and it produces 50 groups as there are 50 different categories found in my dataframe.

The problem now is that I want to form 10 new tables from the 50 subgroups, meaning to say each table will consist of 5 subgroups.

I'll use a smaller data for the example:

```
ID    Category      Colour
01    Chocolate     Pink
02    Ice cream     Purple
03    Candy         Green
04    Popcorn       Yellow
05    Pizza         Blue
06    Pizza         Red
07    Chocolate     Purple
08    Cracker       Brown
09    Chocolate     Black
10    Spaghetti     Yellow
11    Soft drink    Purple
12    Candy         Purple
13    Juice         Red
14    Cookie        Pink
15    Cookie        Grey
```

There are 10 categories in the above example, and by using groupby(), it will create 10 tables (Chocolate, Ice cream, Candy,  Popcorn, Pizza, Cracker, Spaghetti, Soft drink, Juice, Cookie). How can I produce 5 final tables, by combining 2 of the categories together?

Expected result:
Table 1:

```
ID    Category      Colour
01    Chocolate     Pink
07    Chocolate     Purple
09    Chocolate     Black
02    Ice cream     Purple
```

Table 2:

```
ID    Category      Colour
03    Candy         Green
12    Candy         Purple
04    Popcorn       Yellow
```

Table 3:

```
ID    Category      Colour
05    Pizza         Blue
06    Pizza         Red
08    Cracker       Brown
```

and so on. Just to give a rough idea of what combining the groups to form tables means.

Comment: Take a look at the pandas.Series.isin function [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Comment: @TBurgis I don't think that's what I am looking for. Because I won't know all the value of the category nor do I want to know. I just want to add two groups of data together based on their categories.

Comment: So if there are 10 categories you just want to split them into 5 random groups of 2?

Comment: @TBurgis yes. My main point is to combine the groups together to form the final number of groups that I want, which in this case, 5 final groups

Comment: OK. I'm going to add an answer. Hope it's what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` has a column called `category` first we get a list of all the categories and then split it into pairs:

```
all_categories = df['category'].unique()
category_pairs = all_categories.reshape(-1,2)
```

Then we can split the `df` into the pairs:

```
combined_dfs = [df[df['category'].isin(pair)] for pair in category_pairs]
```

`combined_dfs` will be a list of 5 DataFrames each containing two categories. To show what's in each of them:

```
for combined_df in combined_dfs:
    combined_df.head()
```

Comment: @T Burgis Thanks for your reply. I tried it on the given data set, and managed to get the results. However, when I try it on my actual data (more than 2000 data) with 50 categories, I can't get the result. The only thing i should change is the 'reshape(x,y)' am i wrong?